# Автоматическое переключение песни в массиве через JS после завершения проигрывания

Tags: javascript, reactjs, аудио

Решил доделать свой плеер, но столкнулся с проблемой в данном моменте.
Моя реализация:

```js
 let [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
 const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState(songs[index]);
 
   useEffect(() => {
    playing ? myPlayer.current.play() : myPlayer.current.pause();
    setDuration(myPlayer.current.duration);
    myPlayer.current.addEventListener("ended", function (e) {
      console.log(index, currentSong, setCurrentSong);
      setIndex(++index)
      setCurrentSong(songs[index]);
    });
  });
```

Первая песня переключается нормально, а дальше индекс сначала инкрементирует, а потом возвращается к предыдущему значения. Соответственно, не происходит переключение песни. Подскажите, что я делаю не так?  Причем, если попробовать дальше переключить песню, то выходит ошибка currentSong is undefined

Comment: Странно, но сейчас это работает. Вроде никаких сильных изменений не вносил, но все-равно кажется, что это не оптимальное решение.